# Use class as string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the name of the class in string like this:

```
className = "MyClassName"
```

I have already imported the `MyClassName` in my model.

is there a way to use this:

```
Object = MyClassName()
```

#### What I have thought of

making if else statment like this:

```
if className == "MyClassName":
    Object = MyClassName()
elif className == "MyClass2":
    Object = MyClass2()
```

**I hope there is a better way**

Comment: You could use `object = globals()[className]()`

Comment: The question is.. __Why__ do you want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the current module using `sys.modules[__name__]` and then get the class with `getattr`, like this

```
var = "MyClassName"
import sys
mod = sys.modules[__name__]
getattr(mod, var)()
```

Or as [@lanzz suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21932164/python-use-class-as-string/21932224#comment33221652_21932164),

```
globals()[var]()
```

Suggestion by [@Ashwini Chaudhary in the chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/14859170#14859170),

```
classes = {"MyClassName": MyClassName, "MyClass2": MyClass2}
```

You can then use the `classes` dictionary to get the corresponding classes. I would prefer this way, particularly if the input comes from the user.

Comment: which is the better way, yours or lanzz's?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) function.

```
var = "MyClassName"
ob = eval(var + "()")
```